# Initialize function in twig?

Tags: php, twig

How to initialize functions in .twig file ?

```
<?php function renderCategories($categories, $selected, $button_edit, $column_sort_order, $column_name, $column_action) { ?>
    function body..
<?php } ?>
```

How that function to become in .twig format ?
Like that:

```
{{ function renderCategories(categories, selected, button_edit, column_sort_order, column_name, column_action) }}
```

But how to set end of function ?

Answer (score 3):

Best solution IMHO is to create a **macros**:

```
{# macros.html.twig #}
{% macro renderCategories(categories, selected, button_edit, column_sort_order, column_name, column_action) %}
{# then here goes the body of your macro HTML and loops... #}
{% endmacro %}
```

After defining your macro, you can use it like :

```
{% import "macros.html.twig" as myfunctions %}
{# here you passe your variables (categories, selected...) #}
{{ myfunctions.renderCategories(categories, selected, button_edit, column_sort_order, column_name, column_action) }}
```

Read more about macros here : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html

Comment: Documentation about implementing own functions is rare afaik.. but you could write a class with you helper functions as methods and pass the class as a context variable to your view. There you can access your methods.